# Script for users end remote session

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2, remoteapp

I have a couple of DB servers that each run a RemoteApp that users launch to access said DB. The problem is that the application itself does not always exit gracefully when the user ends it, which leaves a remote session open and the user is unable to access said app again.

What I am trying to create a script that would terminate any current existing connection to each specific server (i.e. Script A would terminate for RemoteApp A, Script B would terminate for RemoteApp B).

Not sure if it adds an extra complication but the users are all working in a Remote Desktop environment (i.e. user connects to RDS1 or RDS2 and then launch RemoteApps to DB1, DB2 etc. from there).

All servers are running Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Not sure if this meets your requirements, but you could also configure the remote server to automatically end the user's sessions after they've been disconnected for a set amount of time.  No script required.

Comment: I actually have that currently setup, however client has conflicting needs for a way to terminate quickly and to have the session stay open for a significant period of time (idle time of up to half an hour). The joys of IT

Comment: Micky - Any update on this and whether or not the answer I provided helped with the task?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Taskkill](http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html) commands to kill a specific process on a specific server running as a specific username (see below).

> **Kill a process by targeting it based on...**
>
> 1. the remote server name which it's running
> 2. the username running the process
> 3. the process name on the remote server

---

**Example Command**

<sup>*Be sure to set the appropriate values in the `<RemoteServerName>`, `<Username>`, and `<appname.exe>` parts of the taskkill command below accordingly for your environment and needs.*</sup>

```
TASKKILL /S <RemoteServerName> /F /FI "USERNAME eq <Username>" /IM <appname.exe>
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**Taskkill**](http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html)
- **`Taskkill /?`**
- > ```
  > /S    system           Specifies the remote system to connect to.
  >
  > /FI   filter           Applies a filter to select a set of tasks.
  >                        Allows "*" to be used. ex. imagename eq acme*
  >
  > /F                     Specifies to forcefully terminate the process(es).
  >
  > /IM   imagename        Specifies the image name of the process
  >                        to be terminated. Wildcard '*' can be used
  >                        to specify all tasks or image names
  >
  > Filters:
  >
  >       USERNAME      eq, ne              User name in [domain\]user
  >                                         format
  > ```

Comment: Interesting, I'll have a play around with this. Thank you

Comment: @Mickycampbell No problem, just be sure to let me know if this works for you, feel free to upvote my answer if you'd like, and also feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you find it to be the solution you're looking for satisfying your needs.